# Can STM32 Blue Pill work with JTA 1050 CAN Transceiver?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, can-bus

I currently work on Project CAN communication using stm32f103c8t6 , I have already bought TJA1050 as CAN transceiver but when I try to send CAN message ,the register CAN transmit status register (CAN_TSR) at bit TERR0 is set , that mean transmit failed right ?

When debugging, I checked the CAN Error status register ,the TEC counter is full and the Last Error Code is Bit dominant Error

Did I config wrong or TJA1050 wasn't compatible cause I saw some tutorial CAN stm32 , they use MCP2551 instead of TJA1050 ...
Main code func below :

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_CAN_Init();
  HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
  TxHeader.StdId = 0x446;
  TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
  TxHeader.DLC = 2;

  TxData[0] = 0x50;
  TxData[1] = 0xAA;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      if(HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox) != HAL_OK)
      {
         Error_Handler();
      }
      HAL_Delay(3000);

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
static void MX_CAN_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 1 */
  hcan.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan.Init.Prescaler = 4;
  hcan.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_15TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 2 */

}
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: You mean TJA1050, right?

Comment: The most common beginner mistake is to send things out on the CAN bus with nobody there to listen. Is this what you are doing? Check out my little CAN error frame FAQ here: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)

Comment: Btw your TQ settings are weird. The most normal setup by far is 16 TQ where the sample point is at 14 TQ or 87.5% of the bit length. 15 +2 would give you 17 TQ. Also this depends on how your particular CAN controller counts TQ, sometimes they count in 1 TQ for a sync segment at the start of the bit, sometimes they count this together with the first segment. (Formally the CAN spec divides each bit in sync segment, propagation segment, phase segment 1 and phase segment 2.)

Comment: I just use 1 node for this test , maybe this is root of bug . Thank for your help Lundin and useful information about TQ setting , I using http://www.bittiming.can-wiki.info/ to calculate QT setting with Clock Rate 36MHz and bitrate expect 500kb/s.

Comment: Is that old site still alive? :) Please note that the recommended sample point is at 87.5% for most baudrates no matter CAN controller. And well, these are the things that a real HAL is supposed to take care of you. "ST HAL" is not a proper HAL however, just a bloat layer wrapping up register accesses, but not providing much in the way of actual hardware abstraction.

Comment: You haven't even specified, how if and how you handle the S-pin of the TJA1050. If connected to a GPIO pin, you should at some point set it to LOW, that the transmitter is actually enabled. S-Pin = HIGH sets the transceiver in SILENT MODE (Transmitter disabled) The other thing is, you need someone on the bus, to actually acknowledge the CAN Frame (ACK bit). You should also make sure, you have proper termination used.